# ng-include: Access child scope issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-include, daypilot

I'm using DayPilot Scheduler in my app and i'm having the following issue.

home.html:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <daypilot-scheduler id="scheduler" daypilot-config="schedulerConfig" daypilot-events="events"></daypilot-scheduler>
</div>
```

I access daypilot scheduler in my controller like this:

```
$scope.scheduler;
```

This works when daypilot directive is directly inside home.html like in home.html above, but returns undefined when I include daypilot with ng-include:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div ng-include src="'partials/partial1.html'"></div>
</div>
```

partial1.html:

```
<section>   
    <daypilot-scheduler id="scheduler" daypilot-config="schedulerConfig" daypilot-events="events"></daypilot-scheduler>
</section>
```

If it's included with ng-include, $scope.scheduler returns undefined. scheduler is placed under $$childTail as $$childeTail.scheduler.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I access $$childTail?

Comment: Trying using $parent

Comment: Can you replicate a small example in Plunker?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `$parent.` prefix to `id` attribute's value. So partial1.html will be:

```
<section>   
    <daypilot-scheduler id="$parent.scheduler" daypilot-config="schedulerConfig" daypilot-events="events"></daypilot-scheduler>
</section>
```

And in controller access it like you always did:

```
$scope.scheduler;
```